# Element's href attribute is removed with javascript but still it is present in page source

Tags: javascript, html, css, href

I tried to remove a `link href` attribute with javascript. Javascript is below:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("link[href*='style.css']").remove();        
 });
 </script>
```

HTML

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
```

It finely removes link's href attribute. But when i viewed site's page source using browser then that attribute is still present there. How can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

The page source is what was downloaded originally.  The browser parses the HTML and builds the DOM (Document Object Model), which is an in-memory data structure containing the browser's internal representation of your *rendered* page.

Javascript updates the DOM, not the source.

If you want to see the updated DOM you must use a tool like Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that only removes the CSS link node but does not remove the rules, since the page has already loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //content of function that you need to use
});
```